# when calling a class constructor defined to take several input arguments, a TypeError, saying that the constructor function takes no arguments, occurs

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror

I defined a class called ReplayMemory with the following constructor:

```
class ReplayMemory:
    def __int__(self, mem_size, state_dim, action_dim):
        self.mem_size = mem_size
        self.mem_cntr = 0

        self.state_memory = np.zeros((self.mem_size, state_dim))
        self.action_memory = np.zeros((self.mem_size, action_dim))
        self.reward_memory = np.zeros(self.mem_size)
        self.new_state_memory = np.zeros((self.mem_size, state_dim))
        self.done_memory = np.zeros(self.mem_size, dtype=np.bool)
```

In another class called ddpgAgent I defined a class attribute called memory which is of the object type of the previous class ReplayMemory:

```
class ddpgAgent:
    def __int__(self, state_dim, action_dim, env,
                lr_actor=0.001, lr_critic=0.002,
                discount_factor=0.99, mem_size=1e6, polyak=0.005,
                layer1_size=40, layer2_size=30, batch_size=64, noise=0.1):
        self.memory = ReplayMemory(mem_size, state_dim, self.action_dim)
```

Similarly, I call the constructor function of the class ddpgAgent in the main function in order to create an object of type ddpgAgent.

```
def DDPG():
    env = gym.make('MountainCarContinuous-v0', render_mode='human')
    agent = ddpgAgent(state_dim=env.observation_space.shape[0], action_dim=env.action_space.shape[0], env=env)
```

However, whenever I run the code I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\begbu\PycharmProjects\DDPG-for-continuous-2D-robot\_main.py", line 88, in <module>
    DDPG()
  File "C:\Users\begbu\PycharmProjects\DDPG-for-continuous-2D-robot\_main.py", line 9, in DDPG
    agent = ddpgAgent(state_dim=env.observation_space.shape[0], action_dim=env.action_space.shape[0], env=env)
TypeError: ddpgAgent() takes no arguments
```

Also, I use PyCharm as IDE and whenever I move the mouse over the input arguments of the called constructor functions of ddpgAgent and ReplayMemory in the code, a window pop ups saying there are 'unexpected arguments'.

I have no idea where this error stems from, so I am grateful for any kind of help in this issue. Thank you in advance!

Initially, I thought this strange error stemmed from the IDE sort of. So I ran the code from a terminal. But the same error message occured.

Comment: in ddpgAgent; `self.memory = ReplayMemory(mem_size, state_dim, self.action_dim)` Should the last arg just be `action_dim` without self since you aren't setting it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consturctuor's name should be `__init__`, not `__int__`, e.g.:

```py
class ReplayMemory:
    def __init__(self, mem_size, state_dim, action_dim):
        #   ^--- Here!
```